# What is Encapsulation and how can be understood by practically or with an example in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, encapsulation

Please explain with an examples.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data encapsulation...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004768/data-encapsulation)

Answer (score 0):

Searching in Stackoverflow or Google would have brought you at least this thread as result.

[Data encapsulation...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004768/data-encapsulation)

If this is not what you want, please edit your question so that is more precise in what you want to know.